# Pass argument to UnityEvent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, I'm confused a bit. I studied `UnityEvent` and Messaging System by [this](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events-creating-simple-messaging-system) tutorial. But I have one question, that I cannot understand. How can I pass arguments to Invoking function?

For example(I have `EventManager` like in tutorial):

```
void OnEnable() {
        EventManager.StartListening ("OnPlayerTeleport", TeleportPlayer);
    }

    void OnDisable() {
        EventManager.StopListening ("OnPlayerTeleport", TeleportPlayer);
    }

    void TeleportPlayer () {
        float yPos = transform.position.y;
        yPos += 20.0f;
        transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, yPos, transform.position.z);
    }
```

And I have trigger:

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Teleport")) {
        EventManager.TriggerEvent ("OnPlayerTeleport");
    }
}
```

But, what if I want to pass 'height' value to function 'TeleportPlayer':

```
void TeleportPlayer (float h) {
    float yPos = transform.position.y;
    yPos += h;
    transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, yPos, transform.position.z);
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use C# delegate/Action instead of Unity's `UnityEvent`. It is faster than Unity's event. I ported [*it*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42034899/3785314) few days ago. You just need to modify that a little bit to get what you are looking for.

**1**.Make `Action` take `float` by changing all `Action` declaration to `Action<float>` which means that it will allow functions with `float` parameter.

**2**.Now, make the `TriggerEvent` function take a `float` parameter. by changing

```
public static void TriggerEvent(string eventName)
```

to

```
public static void TriggerEvent(string eventName, float h)
```

Here is the new `EventManager` script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class EventManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Dictionary<string, Action<float>> eventDictionary;

    private static EventManager eventManager;

    public static EventManager instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (!eventManager)
            {
                eventManager = FindObjectOfType(typeof(EventManager)) as EventManager;

                if (!eventManager)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("There needs to be one active EventManger script on a GameObject in your scene.");
                }
                else
                {
                    eventManager.Init();
                }
            }

            return eventManager;
        }
    }

    void Init()
    {
        if (eventDictionary == null)
        {
            eventDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action<float>>();
        }
    }

    public static void StartListening(string eventName, Action<float> listener)
    {

        Action<float> thisEvent;
        if (instance.eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
        {
            thisEvent += listener;
        }
        else
        {
            thisEvent += listener;
            instance.eventDictionary.Add(eventName, thisEvent);
        }
    }

    public static void StopListening(string eventName, Action<float> listener)
    {
        if (eventManager == null) return;
        Action<float> thisEvent;
        if (instance.eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
        {
            thisEvent -= listener;
        }
    }

    public static void TriggerEvent(string eventName, float h)
    {
        Action<float> thisEvent = null;
        if (instance.eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
        {
            thisEvent.Invoke(h);
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{

    void OnEnable()
    {
        EventManager.StartListening("OnPlayerTeleport", TeleportPlayer);
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        EventManager.StopListening("OnPlayerTeleport", TeleportPlayer);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Teleport"))
        {
            EventManager.TriggerEvent("OnPlayerTeleport", 5);
        }
    }

    void TeleportPlayer(float h)
    {
        float yPos = transform.position.y;
        yPos += h;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, yPos, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. But can I ask one more question? What if I have many function and some of them have `float` arguments, some have `string`, and some go without argument?

Comment: @AlexandrKöln It get's complicated from there but can be done. You can create a class called AllData then have all the variables in it. Maybe array strings or floats. Then, change the float parameter to that AllData class type. Now you can pass a class that contains all your information in it.

Comment: Another way is to use the `params` keyword to pass unlimited variables. Instead of making the type `float or `string`, make it `object` type. You can then cast the object to or from `float` or `string` My advice to you is to only pass in what you need. Don't make an EventSystem that can pass every data type in its parameter. This will slow down your game.

Comment: Ok. And what if I will sstore all variables in my GameManager class (I use singleton), and every function that I need will use variable from it instance?
For example: `float height = 15.0f;` in my GameManager, and in function I will just use `GameManager.instance.height`?
I mean, this will be faster and more optimal for code?

Comment: You can use any class you want but singleton does not make code fast in any way. It is simply used to have one instance of a class. I suggest you read more about singleton in C#.

Comment: I mean, your phrase: "Don't make an EventSystem that can pass every data type in its parameter. This will slow down your game."
What will faster: passing parameters or get this parameter from the instance of other class?
P.S. I read about singleton and about C# `params` keyword. And I liked `params` solution. It looks like what I needю

Comment: "get this parameter from the instance of other class" is faster in your case. Avoid [params](http://www.somasim.com/blog/2015/04/csharp-memory-and-performance-tips-for-unity/) for the performance reason I talked about.

Comment: The question is specifically about UnityEvent, not finding alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Create a typed subclass of unityevent to take a parameter that is passed through to listeners and invoke that instead.

Documentation with an example using integer data is here
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_1.html