# Using third party packages in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using UFPS in my FPS game.
UFPS has a class vp_DamageHandler. It's attached to my target. Inside this class, there's:

```
public virtual void Die()
{
dieFunctionCalled = true; //the only thing I've added to this class, besides declaring dieFunctionCalled
...some UFPS code...//among other things, this is where the object is destroyed or deactivated
}
```

I want to keep the original files as clean as possible. I want to do my own coding in a different script to keep things tidy.

I want to do some other things when the target dies, so I've added `myScript` to my target as well, and tried this:

```
void Update () {
        if (GetComponent<vp_DamageHandler> ().dieFunctionCalled) {
            GetComponent<vp_DamageHandler> ().dieFunctionCalled = false;
            Debug.Log ("dieFunctionCalled");
        }
}
```

The problem is that the target is destroyed before the dieFunctionCalled is set to true. So the moment the target dies, myScript is deactivated and doesn't log `dieFunctionCalled`. If I would respawn the target, `dieFunctionCalled` does show up in the console.

I've tried attaching `myScript` to a empty GameObject, but then I get

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Anyone who can help me with this? I'm new to Unity. Basically, all I want is to keep the original UFPS files as clean as possible, and write all my scripts in a different file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried attaching myScript to a empty GameObject, but then I get
>   *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

Create an empty GameObject called "DamageHandlerHolder" then Attach the script to it.

Find the Object that is holding the script

```
GameObject oObj = GameObject.Find("DamageHandlerHolder");
```

Get the script attached to it

```
vp_DamageHandler vpDm = oObj.GetComponent<vp_DamageHandler>();
```

Now you can check the variable:

```
if(vpDm.dieFunctionCalled){}
```

This solves your null problem but I suggest you use [`EventManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034245/unity-eventmanager-with-delegate-instead-of-unityevent) to register to events and be notified the player dies.

Comment: The EventManager was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!