# How can I simplify this long series of if statements?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity to make a game. I have multiple animal enemies in the game.

I'm working on missions inside the game that you have to kill a random number of random animals, this I already have.

What I have a problem with is to increase the mission count when you kill an  animal.

I got a script (dead) sitting on each animal, when the animal dies it calls a public function inside the dead script.

From the dead script it should increase an int value in the "MissionHolder" script where all the animals have a int value to increase when you kill a animal.

The problem is I don't know which animal gets killed when the player kills a animal, what I did is this:

```
public string Name;
public MissionHolder missionHolder;
    public void Kill()
{
    if (name == "Tiger")
    {
        missionHolder.Tiger += 1;
    }

    if (name == "Hyena")
    {
        missionHolder.Hyena += 1;
    }

    if (name == "Gorilla")
    {
        missionHolder.Gorilla += 1;
    }

    if (name == "Giraffe")
    {
        missionHolder.Giraffe += 1;
    }

    if (name == "Gazelle")
    {
        missionHolder.Gazelle += 1;
    }
```

etc.

Now I just name each animal by its name on the dead script but this is not really efficient.

Does anyone knows a better way to do this?

Comment: Please come up with a more descriptive title. No-one can find your question with this title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary`. Register all the animal types as a string then use `Action` as the value in the `Start` or `Awake` function. That `Action` will contain all the names you currently have in your `if` statements. When you want to kill an animal, check if it is in that `Dictionary` then execute the `Action`.

```
public string Name;
public MissionHolder missionHolder;

Dictionary<string, Action> animalToAction = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

void Start()
{
    //Register and animal type and Action
    animalToAction.Add("Tiger", delegate { missionHolder.Tiger += 1; });
    animalToAction.Add("Hyena", delegate { missionHolder.Hyena += 1; });
    animalToAction.Add("Gorilla", delegate { missionHolder.Gorilla += 1; });
    animalToAction.Add("Giraffe", delegate { missionHolder.Giraffe += 1; });
    animalToAction.Add("Gazelle", delegate { missionHolder.Gazelle += 1; });
}
```

Your new Kill function:

```
public void Kill()
{
    //If the name exists in the dictionary, execute the corresponding delegate
    Action action;

    if (animalToAction.TryGetValue(Name, out action))
    {
        //Execute the approprite code
        action();
    }
}
```

You can use [`EventManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034245/unity-eventmanager-with-delegate-instead-of-unityevent/42034899#42034899) to do this but it's not necessary.

Comment: I never worked with the dictionary before so it's kinda hocus pocus for me.

Comment: When i use this code nothing happens, if i kill the tiger it won't add 1 to it.

Comment: Got it, name should have been Name, my fault works great thanks.

Comment: Got it, i will go threw my posts and check the answers. Thanks again