# What is the most optimal way of communication between scripts in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Say, for example, that I have a GameObject A with a Manager script attached, which on start spawns in x amount of GameObjects with B script attached.

A different GameObject with script C is supposed to do something when the GameObject with script B says so.

So the questions is, what would be the best way for these three to communicate?

Obviously, Script B could just call Script C, however I feel like this method lacks structure and organisation.

Script A could also have reference to script C, and script B could tell the Script A to act on Script C.

I feel like there is some sort of rule I am supposed to follow, however I haven't come across it yet. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "this method lacks structure and organization"? Can you show us your code structure?

Comment: This is just an abstract question and I currently do not have an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Obviously, Script B could just call Script C, however I feel like this
>   method lacks structure and organisation.

True. This is what the [`GameObject.SendMessage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) function is used for. Unfortunately, it is slow and I wouldn't recommend it but it's worth mentioning.

If you have many objects that will need to communicate with other objects, implement an event manager with `event` and `delegate`. This is the proper way to do it. You can find full [`EventManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42034899/3785314) implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42034899/3785314).

With it, you can register any amount of function to an event with:

```
EventManager.StartListening("jump", someFunction);
```

Un-register any function from an event with:

```
EventManager.StopListening("jump", someFunction);
```

From there, you can invoke the event on any object listening to it:

```
EventManager.TriggerEvent("jump");
```

Answer (score 1):

If A already has a reference to script C, it can pass on this reference to B, when it is created. Thus, B can communicate with C, without going through A.

i.e

```
Script A:
// variables
     public ScriptC c;

// methods
void SpawnB(){
    // spawn B
    B.setC(c); // B's variable for script C is passed in from A
}

Script B:
// variables
     ScriptC c;
// methods
void setC(ScriptC v){
    c = v;
}
```

Something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the not Unity specific `Action` delegates. I like to use a static class for that but you could as well implement it in one of your existing classes (as long as you use `static` members and methods)

E.g.

```c#
public static class MyEvents 
{
    public static event Action SomeEvent;

    public static void InvokeSomeEvent()
    {
         // Make sure event is only invoked if someone is listening
         if (SomeEvent == null) return;

        SomeEvent.Invoke();
    }
}
```

This makes your classes completely independent (well, ok they share the MyEvents class) and easy to modularize.

In script `C` add a "listener" e.g.

```c#
private void Start()
{
    // It is save to remove a listener also if it wasn't there yet
    // This makes sure you are not listening twice by accident
    MyEvents.SomeEvent -= OnSomeEvent;


    // Add the listener for that event
   MyEvents.SomeEvent += OnSomeEvent;
}

private void OnSomeEvent ()
{
    // Do something if SomeEvent is invoked
}
```

Then somewhere in script `B` just call

```c#
MyEvents.InvokeSomeEvent();
```

So class `B` doesn't have to know or care who listens for that event; it just invokes it and cares for it's own business.

On the other side `C` or (any other class where you add a listener for the event) doesn't have to know/cares where the invoke came from; it just handles it and does its stuff.

Note however, that this also makes debugging a little bit harder since it is not that easy anymore to tell where the invoke came from ;)

---

Note: You can also add parameters to an `Action` e.g.

```c#
public static event Action<int> SomeParameterEvent;
```

In this case ofcourse all methods have to also implement that parameter

```c#
public static InvokeSomeParameterEvent(int value)
{
    if(SomeParameterAction == null) return;

    SomeParameterEvent.Invoke(value);
}
```

In `C` (the listener) you also have to receive the parameters

```c#
// name can be changed
private void OnSomeParameterEvent(int value)
{
    //...
}
```

And ofcourse also call it with the parameter in `B`

```c#
MyEvents.InvokeSomeParameterEvent(someInt);
```

---

And than you can take it even on step further and instead of a value or a reference pass a complete `delegate` method as parameter. See examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Delegates and Events are mostly used for comunication as Programmer wrote.

For better structure and organization I would suggest using a MVC pattern or any other design pattern you like. Here you can find a great example of MVC implementation for Unity3D with simple yet powerful notification system:

[Unity with MVC by Eduardo Dias da Costa](https://www.toptal.com/unity-unity3d/unity-with-mvc-how-to-level-up-your-game-development)

In that example you don't need to use delegates/events for communication and you keep everything well organized.

Some of the communication functions used in quoted tutorial in case the link gets deprecated:

1.

```
// Iterates all Controllers and delegates the notification data
   // This method can easily be found because every class is “BounceElement” and has an “app” 
   // instance.
   public void Notify(string p_event_path, Object p_target, params object[] p_data)
   {
      BounceController[] controller_list = GetAllControllers();
      foreach(BounceController c in controller_list)
      {
         c.OnNotification(p_event_path,p_target,p_data);
      }
   }

   // Fetches all scene Controllers.
   public BounceController[] GetAllControllers() { /* ... */ }
```

2.

```
 // This class will give static access to the events strings.
class BounceNotification
{
   static public string BallHitGround = “ball.hit.ground”;
   static public string GameComplete  = “game.complete”;
   /* ...  */
   static public string GameStart     = “game.start”;
   static public string SceneLoad     = “scene.load”;
   /* ... */
}
```

3.

```
 // Handles the ball hit event
   public void OnNotification(string p_event_path,Object p_target,params object[] p_data)
   {
      switch(p_event_path)
      {
         case BounceNotification.BallHitGround:
            app.model.bounces++;
            Debug.Log(“Bounce ”+app.model.bounce);
            if(app.model.bounces >= app.model.winCondition)
            {
               app.view.ball.enabled = false;
               app.view.ball.GetComponent<RigidBody>().isKinematic=true; // stops the ball
               // Notify itself and other controllers possibly interested in the event
               app.Notify(BounceNotification.GameComplete,this);            
            }
         break;

         case BounceNotification.GameComplete:
            Debug.Log(“Victory!!”);
         break;
      } 
   }
```

4.

```
   // Callback called upon collision.
   void OnCollisionEnter() { app.Notify(BounceNotification.BallHitGround,this); }
```

Of course you can still implement MVC and use Delegates and Events. It is just to show another way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://medium.com/@adamramberg/unity-atoms-tiny-modular-pieces-utilizing-the-power-of-scriptable-objects-e8add1b95201) really good article on communicating through Unity's scriptable objects. The removes the need for scripts to have references to each other, facilitating much more modular code. Within that link I shared, I really recommend the links there about Richard Fine and Ryan Hipple's presentations too.